# What is the plural of "cottage tariff"?

Tags: grammatical-number

When there are several cottages each with several tariffs (depending on the season), should the plural be "cottage tariffs" or "cottages tariffs"?

For context, this is to be a section title on a website renting out the cottages.

An explanation of the grammatical rules would be helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Where a noun is used attributively (that is, as an adjective) as *cottage* is in "cottage tariff", it is never* pluralised. Adjectives in English are not inflected for number. If you have more than one tariff for your cottages, it's *cottage tariffs*.

**never* is a long time of course; and English is riddled with exceptions. But as a general rule with an infinitesimal number of exceptions, this is fine. It doesn't apply to foreign expressions like *beaux arts* because adjectives in some other languages are pluralised.